# Do i lose quality when checking "always fit to window"?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I am using vlc to watch the second season of Game of Thrones and i'm wondering if i can set/check the resolution i am running. Also my image which seems like 1080p is a lot smaller than my window size. My biggest question is does checking the box "always fit to window" decrease or spread out my resolution?
I feel like i lose some quality when checking the box but maybe its just me...Let me know what you think.

Comment: Any resolution change will invariably compromise quality to some extent, but the simplest way to watch VLC is just hit F for fullscreen & live with it… assuming you're not trying to do other tasks at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the actual resolution of your video by going to the Tools -> Codec Information window.

Now, to get the most untampered experience, I would uncheck the "Always Fit Window" option to play the video at its native resolution, regardless of the video window size.  Now, this option is checked by default because it doesn't provide a very nice user experience.  Most people would rather have the video fill the video screen they choose.

As far as the quality goes, you'll loose more quality when you take a large video and shrink it.  In this case some of the detail from the image is lost.  When stretching, you don't necessarily loose data, but you'll have parts of the image that have been calculated by the stretching algorithm to compensate for stretching the image.  As long as you are make too big of changes in either direction, you probably won't notice, and in fact this kind of stretching and shrinking is happening all the time on your computer and TV screens.